# How to generate Cloudstack API signature?

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I already have Cloudstack apikey and secretkey,Then how can I generate signature?My java program is:

```
package test;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Sign 
{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
            String apikey="UETJV-Q_G1quXrV84WMHCRbDzWy-ZCUSdtmvsJWdLODMHbfIP4qLQt19CDj_4m1M5yvoZ4I18SdHsBXAtH5Hmw";
            String request=("apikey="+apikey+"&command=listZones").toLowerCase();
            String secret="8q0oR6oPIhB2je9mmgIuuaPJ5mBLkdzsL1BN6OVI8MTfkmW6Y9oHzvlpRiOr5cP612IWH_TTjvfMfKBgKgUMMg";
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(),"HmacSHA1");
            mac.init(keySpec);
            mac.update(request.getBytes());
            byte[] encryptedBytes = mac.doFinal();

            System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedBytes));//result
            }
}
```

HOWVEVR,I just can't pass the credential.Is there any problems?

Comment: Do you have an example of the URL that you generated using the results of this program?

Comment: Thank you!I have solved the problem.

Comment: @dj199008 can you post the solution and mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use cloudmonkey sign request method
https://github.com/apache/cloudstack-cloudmonkey/blob/master/cloudmonkey/requester.py#L203-L214